# Spring Boot 2.7.8 or 3.x upgrade - Tomcat HTTP Status 404 - Not Found on Azure

Tags: spring-boot, azure, tomcat

I'm currently upgrading an application from Spring Boot 2.7.7 to Spring Boot 3.0.2 and hit a 404 at the tomcat.

The interesting thing is that the application works fine on my local machine, but not in the Azure Cloud.
I have the log-level set to DEBUG for org.springframework.web and with Spring Boot 2.7.7 I see the call received in the logs (on Azure) for actuator/info, whereas in Spring Boot 3 I see the application starting successfully but then no further logs.
Any ideas what it could be or what I can try out to debug further?

Comment: Once you've verified that your Azure Cloud settings are correct, make sure that your security rules and firewall settings aren't blocking any ports.  Please check.

Comment: Are there any other security/firewal rules required for Spring Boot 3? Spring Boot 2.7.7 runs fine in the same context. Same build pipeline and app-service in Azure.

Comment: Spring Boot 3 should not have any additional security or firewall rules compared to 2.7.7 but You can compare the dependencies of your Spring Boot 2.7.7 version and Spring Boot 3.0.2 version and see if there are any major changes or new dependencies that could affect the application's behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to a change in Tomcat version in Spring 2.7.8 (and therefore also Spring Boot 3.x) in relation to the Java-Agent used in Docker / within Azure.

Update to the latest java-agent version in the Docker-Image:

DockerFile

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17

COPY "myBuiltApplication.jar" "app.jar"
ADD "https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/releases/download/**3.4.8**/applicationinsights-agent-*3.4.8*.jar" "agent.jar"

EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-javaagent:agent.jar", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Make sure that no other agent is active from Azure

I had to remove the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS and StartupBootstrapper from the docker run:

```
- docker run -d --expose=80 --name myapp
  JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-javaagent:/agents/java/applicationinsights-agent-codeless.jar -e StartupBootstrapper=Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.StartupBootstrapper -e
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue with Spring Boot version 2.7.8 with the exact same behavior: Starting the app local in IDE as well as starting the docker image locally worked perfect. When running this image in Azure as an App Service no http call is going to spring. For me it looks like Tomcat has an issue as the 404 seems to be produced by Tomcat.
Downgrading to Spring Boot 2.7.7 fixed the issue again.

Comment: Have you created a bug report for the Spring team?

Comment: Yes, meanwhile I did: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33974

Comment: I confirm answer from @marco . Ugrading the Java Agent worked for me.